# Missing \endcsname with xr cross referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, zref, xr

I searched a lot, but cannot figure out the following problem:
I am trying to reference another document using the `xr` package. I also tried out `zref` but it does not matter regarding the error message.

**Set up**
In the a4paper document "Formelsammlung_StatistikI+II" I have:

```
\input{chapter/chap1}
\input{chapter/chap2}
```

And in chap2 is the equation I want to reference in the other document "Statistik":

```
\begin{equation}\label{random}
random = random
\end{equation}
```

In the beamer document "Statistik", I have:

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[f:]{Formelsammlung_StatistikI+II}

\begin{document}
\input{chap1}
\end{document}
```

And I want to put the reference in chapter one of "Statistik":

```
Also see \ref{f:random}.
```

**Folder structure**
In the main folder are Statistik.tex and Formelsammlung_StatistikI+II.tex as well as the chapters of Statistik.tex, which are included in Statistik.tex with input(chap1).
In a subfolder are the chapters of Formelsammlung_StatistikI+II.tex, which are also included in Formelsammlung_StatistikI+II.tex with input(chapter/chap1). **The referenced part is in chap2.**

**The error**
Every time I run *Typeset* on TeXShop (latest Mac Version) I get the following error:

> (./xr-hyper.sty
>   Package xr-hyper Warning: Load package `hyperref' after`xr-hyper'. 
>   )
>   ./Statistik.tex:171: Missing \endcsname inserted.
>   
>         \protect
>   l.171

The errors are the same when using the package `zref-xr` and `zexternaldocument`, but instead of xr-hyper.sty it laments `zref-xr.sty` and `zref-base.sty`. However all mentioned .sty files are put in the folder and in the library `texmf/tex/...` folder.

I would very much appreciate your help. It is my first post, so I hope I did not forget something. If so, please let me know.

Regards,
Nic

Comment: I assume that 'Formelsammlung.....tex` is a real compilable document? I tried your example and get no error (not using `zref`, however). I don't think that you need `zref` here at all

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah all documents are compilable without the added xr package. I just gave extracts of the code to keep it simple.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the equation I want to reference, is in one of the chapters of "Formelsammlung....tex". I edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Yes, but what's inside `chap1.tex`? We don't have this stuff here available.

Comment: Just more content. There actually more chapters, but the relevant one is chap2 where the to be referenced equation is.

Comment: Well, anyway, I can't reproduce your issue. It works without error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem laid in the labels of the document to be referenced. There are no problems referencing labels with tab space or special characters within the same document, but **when referencing between documents, no tab space or special characters are allowed in the labels**.
*For example:*

```
\label{eq:equation} % in document to be referenced
\ref{f-eq:equation} % in document that puts the reference
```

works properly.

But...

```
\label{eq: equation one in chapter 2.1}
\label{f-eq: equation one in chapter 2.1}
```

will lead to the error I described above.